# Standard way to render datasource of a sublayout - Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

This works for me, but want to know it's the correct method or there is a better way, to display an item that is set as a datasource to a sublayout.

**sample.ascx**

```
<sc:Text ID="txtHeader" runat="server" Field="Header" />
<br/>
<sc:Image ID="imgMotif" runat="server" Field="Motif Left" />
<br/>
<!-- some more controls -->
```

**sample.ascx.cs**

```
private void BindData()
{
  Item introItem = GetItemFromDatasource((Sublayout)this.Parent);

  if(introItem != null)
  {
    txtHeader.Item = introItem;
    imgMotif.Item = introItem;
    //..and so on..
  }
}

private Item GetItemFromDatasource(Sublayout sublayout)
{
  Item dataSource = null;

  if (sublayout != null)
  {
    Guid dataSourceId;

    if (Guid.TryParse(sublayout.DataSource, out dataSourceId))
       dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(dataSourceId));                
  }
    return dataSource;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest your sublayouts to inherit from a sublayout base.

Your SublayoutBase will look like:

```
public class SublayoutBase : UserControl  
{
 private Item _dataSource;

 public Item DataSource
 {
  get
  {
  if (_dataSource == null)
  {
    if (Parent is Sublayout)
    {
      var sublayout = (Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout)Parent;
      Guid dataSourceId;
      if (Guid.TryParse(sublayout.DataSource, out dataSourceId))
      {
        _dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(dataSourceId));
      }
      else
      {
        _dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(sublayout.DataSource);
      }
    }
    if (_dataSource == null)
    {
      _dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    }
  }
  return _dataSource;
  }
 }
```